# using pandas groupby apply sum & count for two categorical columns based on another categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

apply pandas groupby or pivot function apply aggregate sum & count for two categorical columns based on another categorical column

[image]

output I need

[image]

orgainzation_name   structure   skills

capgemini     team_lead   python

capgemini   manager pmp_certified

capgemini   analyst SQL

wipro   team_lead   python

wipro   manager pmp_certified

wipro   analyst SQL

infosys team_lead   python

infosys manager pmp certifed

infosys analyst SQL

wipro   manager pmp_certifed

wipro   analyst SQL

wipro   analyst SQL

wipro   analyst SQL

wipro   analyst SQL

capgemini   team_lead   python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please post your code and data samples as plain text

Comment: @Patrick , i tried this way df.groupby(['structure','skills']).count()['organization name']

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Please FInd Above shared text format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
df.value_counts(['orgainzation_name','structure','skills'])
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(['orgainzation_name','structure','skills'],ascending=[True,False,True])
)
```

[image]

You can control the sort order by manipulating ascending=.

Comment: it should come in order wise like wipro   analyst  SQL 5 , capgemini analyst SQL 3 Infosys analyst SQL 2

Comment: like analyst SQL should come in orderby [wipro,Capgemini,Infosys], team_lead python in orderby  [wipro,Capgemini,Infosys]